# SSIS - Location of FTP transmission log

Tags: ssis

I Would like to know where I can see the FTP transmission log when I use the "TF Secure FTP Task" locally and from a server?
I've run an SSIS yesterday and all the steps were successful but I was told today that nothing was sent, this is why I'm trying to locate a log file to confirm the transmission.
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SSIS doesn't automatically log FTP transmissions.   If you want to do this in SSIS you will have to code it.

But maybe your FTP server logs transmissions; you should check with the server admin.